# I need to make a page where you can see the beginning of a review, but have to click on 'click more' to see the rest of the review

Tags: javascript, expand

I am putting up a web site for a business and they want a page dedicated to their good reviews of their products.

They however don't want huge paragraphs taking up their page. Is there a way to make it so that for each review there is something they can click on, such as just a line of it, then "click here", that would expand each one individually?

I hade a gentlemen help me a little while back, but it only worked for one entry. I used the same javascript for all 3 and I am thinking that was incorrect.

Also, I am assuming this will expand the height of the page based on how long the review was. I only mention this because I have a footer at the bottom.

Anyway, JavaScript I assume?

```
<div class="comment">
This is the first line of the comment 
<span id="extended_comment"   style="display:none;">and  this    is the rest of the    comment     that is hiddden.</span> <a href="#" id="toggle">click here for more</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var toggle = document.getElementById('toggle');
toggle.onclick = function() {
var extended = document.getElementById('extended_commen…
if(this.innerHTML == 'click here for more') {
 extended.style.display = 'inline';
 this.innerHTML = 'click here for less';
 } else {
 extended.style.display = 'none';
this.innerHTML = 'click here for more';
}
};
</script>
```

Comment: [tag:java] tag removed and [tag:javascript] tag added. You understand that they are vastly different languages, and if you want the correct experts reviewing your question, you must be very careful to use the correct tags. Luck.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you've already tried (the code from the gentleman, for example).  You can create a working example at jsfiddle.net

Comment: sorry, definitely JavaScript. Typing too quick and distracted. I will try to edit the original with what he suggested

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your code in a function and pass the necessary ids to that function in order to set each element's onclick property.

```
function setExpandOnclick(toggleButton, extendedComment) {
  // your code here, using the arguments rather than hard-coded string ids
}

setExpandOnclick("toggle-button1", "expanded-comment1");
setExpandOnclick("toggle-button2", "expanded-comment2");
```

You were on the right track.

Comment: Thank you. And I promise that I sort of know what I am doing so please bear with me :) Anyway, so regarding the line where you said "your code here" - what information would I be omitting from the original example? toggle...for example?

Comment: Use everything in your current script tag, except replace the getElementById() arguments with those passed into the function (e.g. getElementById(toggleButton)). Also, replace your references to "this" with "toggle" (e.g. toggle.innerHTML).

Comment: Makes sense. I appreciate the assistance!!